# Calculate Percentile of Skewed Dataset

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I am looking to calculate the 90th, 95th and 99th percentile of a dataset.
Normally it is distributed almost Normally.
So I can use Z-value = 1.282, 1.645, 2.326 to approximate the percentiles as follow:  X = u + z*σ

Now what if the Dataset is Skewed.
How do I find the approximation of percentiles of the dataset now?
Do I take the Natural Log of the data to smooth out the skew?

Is there anything I can do with the Calculation of Skewness to get a better mean and standard deviation for my dataset so I can get a more accurate percentile approximation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straightforward way is to use the definition of percentile (which
differs a bit from text to text and software to software) and count
observations. This works for *data* from any distribution. (Differences
in definitions do not matter much for large samples.)
Roughly speaking, the 90th percentile is a value below which one finds
not more than 90% of the observations, and above which one finds not more
than 10% of them.

Here are a few examples of percentiles for a couple of datasets in R, one
normal (symmetrical) and one exponential (right-skewed). Notice that
percentiles of small *samples* do not necessarily match percentiles of
the *populations* from which they are sampled. (The method you have been
using for normal data seems to conflate the two kinds of percentiles.) 
In the data displays below the numbers in brackets give the index of the
first observation in the that row.

```
x = round(sort(rnorm(50, 100, 15)), 1);  x  # generate 50 obs from Norm mean=100, SD=15
x
 [1]  61.1  69.4  71.1  73.0  73.9  77.5  78.0  78.0  79.0  81.5
[11]  83.4  85.9  86.5  87.8  87.9  88.0  88.8  90.0  90.7  91.3
[21]  92.0  93.0  95.3  97.9  97.9  99.2  99.2 100.0 100.2 101.0
[31] 102.9 103.4 104.3 104.6 105.4 107.2 108.5 108.6 109.5 109.6
[41] 111.3 111.5 111.9 118.0 119.5 119.6 119.6 119.9 121.5 128.4
quantile(x, .9)  # 90th percentile
   90% 
119.51 
quantile(x, .7)  # 70th percentile
   70% 
105.94 
qnorm(c(.9, .7), 100, 15)  # 90th and 70th percentiles of POPULATION
[1] 119.2233 107.8660

x = round(sort(rexp(60, rate=1/50)), 1);  x  # generate 60 obs from EXP mean=50
x
 [1]   0.0   0.4   0.5   0.9   0.9   1.3   2.4   3.8   4.4   6.1
[11]   7.5   7.9   8.0   9.0   9.9  11.0  11.5  13.3  15.4  16.4
[21]  19.6  20.3  25.1  25.4  28.0  28.8  29.3  29.5  31.1  32.0
[31]  32.1  34.2  37.2  40.6  42.0  42.0  49.5  52.2  55.6  56.8
[41]  59.6  64.3  73.9  74.7  78.7  87.9  90.1  95.4  97.2 105.2
[51] 110.3 113.8 114.6 172.5 187.0 188.2 188.8 207.9 259.7 265.3
quantile(x, .9)
   90% 
173.95 
quantile(x, .7)
  70% 
67.18 
qexp(c(.9, .7), rate=1/50)  # 90th and 70th percentiles of POPULATION
115.12925  60.19864
```

Comment: The dataset I have is huge, with billions of data. so if I use my current method. Will there be a big error on the percentile calculation?

Comment: Probably not, if the data are truly normal (which is quite an assumption). One method of testing for normality essentially checks to see how well sample and normal population percentiles match.

Comment: Do you think there is another way of calculating the percentile? I tried Frequency table before. But I think Frequency table actually takes longer to process than a normal distribution although it is more precise with the answer.

Comment: Some software sorts the data before finding percentiles. With huge datasets that can take time. Maybe quicker to guess the quantile assuming normality, _and then verify_ that the required number of observations is really less than the guess.